# Android - AlarmManager or TimerTask/Timer to perform action in x hour's time?

Tags: android, timer, alarmmanager, android-alarms, timertask

My app needs to perform `myAction()` 12 or 24 hours after the user clicks a button.

I understand I can't use `handler.postDelayed(Runnable, long)` for this because the `long` argument is based on [uptime](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis()) rather than actual time.

So I think I am just left with [TimerTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)/[Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) or [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), but I'm not sure which of these would be most appropriate - plus, I hear a lot of bad comments about TimerTask/Timer, saying that it's unreliable, etc.

Also, I have the requirement where if the device is restarted, then I still need `myAction()` to be performed at the same time it would have been (or as soon after as possible) as if the device had never been turned off. For this requirement, maybe I need to store details of `myAction()` in the database and then use a BootReceiver to recall it for execution when the device restarts, but it would nice if there was a class that could take care of this, too.

So what would be an appropriate and reliable way of calling `myAction()` in 12/24 hours time, whilst accommodating device restarts?

Comment: "I hear a lot of bad comments about TimerTask/Timer, saying that it's unreliable" -- well, it assumes that your process will live that long. That is unlikely unless it is a foreground service, and that tends to irritate the user unless there is an obvious reason for it. And there is no guarantee that your process will live that long even if it is a foreground service, though it is more likely. In general, trying to do background work at specific times, other than alarm clock scenarios, is going to be fairly aggravating, given the ongoing War on Background Processing.

Answer (score 1):

Use GCM Network Manager or Firebase Job Dispatcher.
These are the 2 best practice approaches to doing periodic work on Android.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager#run_tasks

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

(Note, although the name implies that they are related to push messaging, they are not. Both are solutions for running periodic work locally on a device.)

Comment: I tried the Firebase Job Dispatcher approach, but that did not work across device reboot. However, the GCM Network Manager approach did work after restarting my device. (To persist across device reboots, you just need to add `.setPersisted(true)` to your `OneoffTask.Builder`.) Have only tested it with a window of 1 to 3 minutes so far, so will check it with a 24 to 25 hour window next, then I'll post an update here. By the way, there's an excellent GCM Network Manager tutorial here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-network-manager/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0 .

Comment: Btw, both GCM Network Manager and the FB alternative support persisting across reboot.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll stick with GCM Network Manager anyway as `myAction()` is performing is networking stuff anyway.